# Can't see the right pane in p4v

Tags: perforce, p4v

After I created a new workspace I stopped being able to see the right pane (workspace area). I tried View->history, View->pending changelists....but is till see only the left pane taking all the space.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I occasionally accidentally get myself in the opposite situation (where the right pane is the only one I see). Try hovering near the right side of the left pane and see if you can bring up the little <||> then grab it and move it to the left.

Comment: @tkosinski I can't believe I fell for this trap :). Yes, that was it. Thanks!